# Can't browse the library on google cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to scraping using lravel's "Goutte", it succeeds in the local environment, but I get an error in the Google Cloud environment. Probably not referenced in the "use" part of the controller.

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNJJw.png)

I referred to [this site](https://qiita.com/Kouhei56/items/b6832a76910babb99d8d) for how to use "Goutte".

The controller used is as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// Probably not able to refer to this ---------|
use Weidner\Goutte\GoutteFacade as GoutteFacade;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $goutte = GoutteFacade::request('GET', 'https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/bestsellers/electronics/3946818051?ref_=Oct_BSellerC_3946818051_SAll&pf_rd_p=7019a35e-d4ad-5da4-8fdd-f9f5c8ef9428&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-10&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=3946818051&pf_rd_m=AN1VRQENFRJN5&pf_rd_r=61C7KYXHQFEAY80RGM67&pf_rd_r=61C7KYXHQFEAY80RGM67&pf_rd_p=7019a35e-d4ad-5da4-8fdd-f9f5c8ef9428');

        $images = [];
        $texts = [];

        $goutte->filter('.a-dynamic-image')->each(function ($node) use (&$images) {
            $images[] = $node->attr('src');
        });

        $goutte->filter('.p13n-sc-truncate')->each(function ($node) use (&$texts) {
            $texts[] = $node->text();
        });

        $params = [
            'images' => $images,
            'texts' => $texts,
        ];

        return view('book.index',$params);
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
        // add
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.3.0",
        "weidner/goutte": "^1.6"
    },
```

config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
           // add
           Weidner\Goutte\GoutteServiceProvider::class, 
]

'aliases' => [
        // add
        'Goutte' => Weidner\Goutte\GoutteFacade::class,
]
```

**Postscript**
@Hamelraj
[Is this image consistent with cloud composer updates?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v07tE.png)
Also, the error does not improve even if I deploy it again. Is it correct with the recognition that "gcloud app deploy" is executed again locally?

Comment: have you updated composer in cloud  after installing this package?

Comment: @hamelraj
No.
I don't know how to update compsoer in the cloud so please let me know.

Comment: If anyone knows how to use an external library on google cloud, can you tell me?

Comment: i checked in cloud console it has composer tab. try with it else you need to re deploy whole codes again

Comment: @Hamelraj
Excuse me
I added to the question, but I don't have enough understanding about google cloud, can you tell me a detailed answer?